# Determine word boundaries in a python string

Tags: python, nlp

I have filepaths in the format of:

```
THISISSOMEMOVIE.mov
```

Is there some NLP library that can make very educated/statistical guesses about the word boundaries in a string? For example, the above should be parsed as:

```
THIS IS SOME MOVIE mov
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a library that does just that but you could use [PyEnchant](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/) that tells you if a word belongs to the dictionary.

So here's the pseudo code of what I'd do:

```
 s = 0
 i = len(title) - 1
 check if the substring s-i is in the dictionary
    if not i = i - 1
    if yes then s becomes i+1, and i = len(title) - 1 again
```

Comment: that's a good idea. Though it would have to be greedy (to an extent). That is, using the above approach it would parse "This" "I"...then no word that starts with two s's.

Comment: not if you search a word starting from the longest substring right? In the case I described above after finding This, it'd check if `issomemovie` is a word then `issomemovi` and so one until `is` is indeed a word and so on. There might be instances where word1+word2 actually form a word but that should be rare